# How to map states of usa with cities in salesforce

Tags: dependent-picklist

Currently I have a requirement to map all the states of usa with respect to their cities.

I know it can be made with the help of controlling picklist but is there any option to make the process ease as I can see that some of the states are having upto 150 cities.

Please let me know is there any other easy process.

Please help

Comment: New object - State, 
New Object - Cities, 
connected with a parent - child relationship

Comment: Tim I know the process but is there any easy way since I would have to map 200 cities for every one state

Comment: Do you mean as in to create the data once you have the objects in place?

Comment: Once you have this set up, you can use Data loader or import wizard to insert the data.

Comment: +1 for dataloader, you can create all the data in a spreadsheet and just upload it into the objects

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but mind the limits for picklists: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=picklist_limitations.htm&language=en. You can only have 1000 entries in one picklist. It lokks like this might conflict with your requirements.

Comment: I don't want to insert the data using data loader.I just need to setup two picklists having states of usa and cities of usa.When I would be defining controlling picklist e.g. Massachusettes having 29 cities so for 50 states* 100 cities .How can I ease this as this process would require one week to map when defining controlling fields

Comment: State and Country picklist doesn't work for you? https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_state_country_picklists_overview.htm